# Pourquoi dire « ma journée s’est bien déroulée » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Pourquoi utilise-t-on le verbe « se dérouler » dans ce cas ?

Cet usage du verbe serait-il métaphorique ?

ps: Peut-être comprendrez-vous mieux ce que je vous demande si je vous dis que l'expression est tirée du livre *Metaphors we live by*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« se dérouler » is used in the figurative sense, which implies un underlying metaphore; however it's a set metaphor, rather stricly defined by the dictionaries, not what we mean usually by "metaphor", that is the often unique use by an author of a term or phrase in place of another in order to create a special effect, that to which is given the more familiar term "figure of speech". In this figurative sense, using a quite nicely coincidental English word in a figurative way, it means "to unfurl"; this term is however litterary. A much less metaphorical rendering, but proper for everyday use would be "to go"; thus you would keep to the mind of the French by translating it "My day went well". The reason for saying "ma journée s'est bien déroulée" rather than for instance "ma journée s'est bien passée", that latter being possible if the former is (it "covers" it so to speak), is that you might imply an unusual and rather formal activity that was to take place during that particular day, but such fine distinctions can be commonly disregarded.

Comment: Pourquoi répondre en anglais à une question posée en français ?

Comment: @Toto euh il est la première personne qui a édité ma question, donc il a certainement sait que mon français est très très mauvais.. . . :/ mais, il n’a pas juste sait que mon anglais est mauvais aussi. 

Answer (score 2):

Le dictionnaire Petit Robert n’indique pas une métaphore, mais un usage *figuratif* pour la forme pronominale :

> **Se dérouler** : prendre place dans le temps, en parlant d’une suite ininterrompue d’événements, de pensées.
>
> … Synonymes : *s’écouler, se passer*.

Cela ne ressemble pas à la *[définition de la métaphore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9taphore)*, car le mot *figuratif* englobe l’analogie, mais pas la notion de style littéraire ou poétique.

Comment: @Toto I must say that I am not always as finely inspired in one of those two languages as I am in the other, be it French or English. As I had acquired intuitively the notion, in the course of sharing a few opinions on this site for the past few days, that English was being used freely, and moreover as something of a lingua franca (the membership is thoroughly international) I felt myself totally free of following my inspiration. Should I now be reminded of particular rules concerning the language used?

Comment: @cl-rJe ne parle pas de métaphore mais de métaphore sous jacente et j'aurais peut être dû parler plus justement d'un procédé qui tient de la métaphore; tout terme figuré est fondé sur ce principe de l'analogie; mais vous pourrez remarquer que je ramène la question à une base ne permettant pas la contestation tant soit en français qu'en anglais: je parle de « figure d'expression » puis finalement d'usage figuratif. ...

Comment: @cl-rIl faut comprendre que les termes anglais sont trompeurs pour le français et vice versa, en particulier lorsque on les trouve dans des domaines connexes. Non, je ne crois pas dire qu'en français il sagisse d'une métaphore tel que l'on entend le terme en français; je définis la chose comme « set metaphore » et il aurait peut être fallu des guillemets; cela est encore une métaphore de ma part: la métaphore qui nous intéresse n'en est une que par la notion d'analogie...

Comment: @cl-rqui est impliquée; elle n'en est pas une en cela que la création n'est pas le fait d'un auteur dans un seul ouvrage (n'oublions pas qu'une métaphore peut être réutilisée par n'importe quel auteur et avec cela sans changement d'interprétation) mais une chose en comparaison rigide, fixe (set) pour laquelle on trouve une définition assez stricte dans un dictionnaire et que nous sommes tous sensés utiliser selon cette prescription. Il ne faut faire attention de ne pas mêler l'anglais et le français.

Comment: @user168676 — Ce qui a motivé ma réponse est la notion de *continuité nécessaire au déroulement du temps* qui ne figure pas dans la vôtre. Cette notion est sensible, perceptible par tout un chacun on peut donc *se la figurer*. Une métaphore est un concept académique que des esprits savants peuvent formuler (trente-six *figures de style* dont certaines sont parfois en compétition sur une phrase). C’est l’essence de ma réponse, libre à vous d’ajouter une étiquette métaphorique sur l’exemple proposé en français et de revenir à la définition d’Aristote basée sur la seule analogie.

Comment: @cl-rIl y a certainement une notion de continuité dans l'idée du verbe passer, verbe que vous reprenez vous-même dans votre réponse; je ne vois pas où je sacrifierais la continuité. Quand à ce qu'est une métaphore, certes, c'est une chose délicate à définir soigneusement et tout le monde n'a pas la définition du TLFi au bout des lèvres, mais ce n'est pas une bien grande difficulté, on apprend le principe à des élèves de 4 ième. Je ne pense pas pervertir ces notions dont vous parlez; je n'utilise le terme que selon l'anglais et j'insiste sur le concept commun aux deux langues: usage au figuré.

Comment: @cl-rDéfinition de métaphore dans le TLFi: Figure d'expression par laquelle on désigne une entité conceptuelle au moyen d'un terme qui, en langue, en signifie une autre en vertu d'une analogie entre les deux entités rapprochées et finalement fondues.